Execute `sp_spaceused` only for all databases
Following answer (Execute `sp_spaceused` for all tables in all databases) executes solution for sp_spaceused for all tables in all databases.
Instead can I only execute it for all databases?

I am able to see the results for all databases using following script but if possible I want to see the results in a single excel table, like the linked answer:
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Declare a cursor to loop through all databases
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' -- Filter out offline databases if needed

-- Open the cursor
OPEN database_cursor

-- Fetch the first database name from the cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DatabaseName

-- Start looping through all databases
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Build the dynamic SQL query to switch database context and execute the query
    SET @SqlQuery = 'USE [' + @DatabaseName + ']; EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1'

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL query
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery

    -- Fetch the next database name from the cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DatabaseName
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor
CLOSE database_cursor
DEALLOCATE database_cursor


Example excel-view output, where I can easily copy all rows and paste it into excel file as whole:


Can you clarify your mention of Excel? I don't see that the linked question (164977) involves Excel in any way.

Please see the example output under Results section on my updated question. Linked question has the similar output view

So do you want this for every table in every database, or only aggregated for each database?

@Charlieface I want this only aggregated for each database

You can construct a giant dynamic UNION ALL query using sys.dm_db_partition_stats, with grouping, then execute it.
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = '
select
  name = concat_ws(N''.'', t.db_name, t.schema_name, t.name),
  [rows] = sum(case when t.index_id in (0, 1) then t.row_count end),
  [reserved_MB] = sum(t.reserved_page_count) * 8 / 1024.0,
  data_MB = sum(case when t.index_id in (0, 1) then t.used_page_count end) * 8 / 1024.0,
  index_size_MB = sum(case when t.index_id in (0, 1) then t.used_page_count end) * 8 / 1024.0,
  unused_MB = sum(t.reserved_page_count - t.used_page_count) * 8 / 1024.0
from (' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'
    select
      db_name = N' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ',
      o.name,
      o.schema_id,
      schema_name = sch.name,
      s.*
    from ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
    left join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.objects o on o.object_id = s.object_id
    left join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.schemas sch on sch.schema_id = o.schema_id
'), '
    union all
')
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.database_id > 4   -- only user DBs
      AND d.state IN (0, 5)   -- only online
) + '
) t
group by
  t.db_name,
  t.object_id,
  t.schema_id,
  t.name,
  t.schema_name;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

If you want to aggregate also by database then you can finish off with:
group by grouping sets (
 (
  t.db_name,
  t.object_id,
  t.schema_id,
  t.name,
  t.schema_name
 ),
 (
  t.db_name
 );

If you only want to aggregate by database then you could simplify significantly:
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = '
select
  t.db_name,
  [rows] = sum(case when t.index_id in (0, 1) then t.row_count end),
  [reserved_MB] = sum(t.reserved_page_count) * 8 / 1024.0,
  data_MB = sum(case when t.index_id in (0, 1) then t.used_page_count end) * 8 / 1024.0,
  index_size_MB = sum(case when t.index_id in (0, 1) then t.used_page_count end) * 8 / 1024.0,
  unused_MB = sum(t.reserved_page_count - t.used_page_count) * 8 / 1024.0
from (' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'
    select
      db_name = N' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ',
      s.*
    from ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
'), '
    union all
')
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.database_id > 4   -- only user DBs
      AND d.state IN (0, 5)   -- only online
) + '
) t
group by
  t.db_name;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


I get following error message: Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Turkish_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in GROUP BY statement column 5.  for the first script :-(

Looks like you have differing default collations in your databases. You will need to add COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 or similar to each expression.

Which line should I add it? Second script worked btw

Column 5 is t.schema_name so I guess that one. Both in the GROUP BY and the SELECT.

For each database data_sizes are much different than this scripts shows, what might be the reason for this :  SELECT d.NAME     ,ROUND(SUM(CAST(mf.size AS bigint)) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs     ,(SUM(CAST(mf.size AS bigint)) * 8 / 1024) / 1024 AS Size_GBs FROM sys.master_files mf INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- Skip system databases GROUP BY d.NAME ORDER BY d.NAME

The link for the scipt I pasted above: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/6636ee2481e18af97a25434c03a2608e     // Your solution returns much much less data sizes, which one is correct?

Why would you think they would be the same? There is a lot of empty space that is not reserved yet for indexes or tables, or pages used for database headers and page management etc. The aggregation is only for the actual data pages, which is what sp_spaceused does. Yes obviously you can just use sys.master_files if you want overall file sizes. So they return different things, it depends what you actually want which you haven't really explained.

Please see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/339023/why-there-is-huge-gap-between-allocated-and-used-size-in-azure-sql-mi

Just execute the procedure. By default, it is executed for only the database you are connected to.
The example in your linked question is using the command sp_msforeachdb to do more complicated task of listing space used for every database.

I want to see all databases' result in a single excal table, is it also possible using sp_msforeachdb?

@alper If I were doing that, I'd not use sp_spaceused but instead something more like what is done in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26179417/4979479

I have checked all the solutions and they run on a single databases rather than all

create temp table #result and populate it with output of sp_spaceused like insert into #result EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1
